# Как восстановить базу данных mysql XAMMP?

Tags: mysql, xampp

Умерла система на компе, остались только файлы xammp , в ней таблицы, но вот их копирую в папку нового xammp и mysql не запускается( как их можно восстановить если имеются все файлы?